# Web Api 2 route configuration with legacy asmx services in api folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to add the Web Api functionality to an existing ASP.NET application. This should be something simple but I'v been stuck on this for hours. I've tried a bunch of things but no luck so far.

The app has several asmx services in "/api" folder. This somehow interferes with the web api routing. Ideally, I'd like to keep the existing services in the current place since there are external references to them.

Sample service:
/Api/ApiServ.asmx - I'm able to invoke the initial screen with the method list

The problem is when I try to invoke any method on one of the services e.g. /Api/ApiServ.asmx/ServMethod - I can't invoke this and I'm getting this response: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:49415/api/apiserv.asmx/ServMethod'"

Here is what I have:
Global.asax:

```
public class WebApiApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {            
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        //RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Sample service:

```
namespace WebApiTest.Api
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]    
    [ScriptService]
    public class ApiServ : WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string ServMethod()
        {
            return "Test";
        }
    }
}
```

Web Api Config:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("asmx", "api/{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");           

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Strangely enough, when I use a route debbuger it actually matches the asmx ignore route but the service method is not being hit. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't actually figure out a proper fix as I ran out of time I had allocated for fixing this but since the solution is temporary and will be moving the asmx services to web api controllers I decided to settle for a workaround.

This is what I did:
1) In the /Api folder I created a /Legacy subfolder and moved all asmx services there

2) In global.asax Application_BeginRequest:

```
private void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLower();

    if (url.StartsWith("/api") && url.Contains(".asmx") && !url.Contains("/api/legacy/"))
    {
        url = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Replace("/api/", "/api/legacy/");

        Context.RewritePath(url);
    }
}
```

Note a similar thing could be achieved in a more cultured way such as using the rewrite module but this works for me a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you do have an mvc portion to your API (web api help pages will add mvc)

you will need to add the following line to your RouteConfig.cs:

routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");

and that will do the trick!